# Multiple functions with shared arguments in Manipulate

Tags: functions, manipulate

I am trying to define multiple functions with the same set of parameters and then put them in a Manipulate to simulate their behavior.

Ideally it should be something like that:

```
par={a,b,c};
f[q_,a_,b_,c_]:=q+a+b+c;
g[q_,a_,b_,c_]:=q-a-b-c;
```

Then afterwards I would like to have something like

```
Manipulate[
  Plot[f[q-5, par] + g[q+5, par], {q,0,10}],
  {{a,0},-1,1},{{b,0},-1,1},{{c,0},-1,1}]
```

I know that I can use the Apply command and write something like

```
f @@ par
```

The problem is that then I don't know how to still operate on the q parameter and, in addition, even if I add the q parameter in par and then write f@@par, the Manipulate does not work anymore.

Is it possible to solve this issue or I have to stick with this piece of code?

```
Manipulate[Plot[f[q-5,a,b,c] + g[q+5,a,b,c], {q,0,10}],{{a,0},-1,1},{{b,0},-1,1},{{c,0},-1,1}]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: The problem you're having is because `Manipulate` localizes its variables, while the symbols in `par` are global (in the ``"Global`"`` context).  Your workaround seems reasonable.  There's also the option `LocalizeVariables -> False`, but on the face of it, I prefer your workaround.

Comment: Because I am dealing with a large number of parameters and functions I actually prefer your `LocalizeVariables -> False` workaround that would keep my code way more smooth. The problem is that it does not seem to work even with a single function like `f@@par`.

Comment: Oh my lord but it took me forever to realize that your manipulate function was independent of the values of `a`, `b`, and `c`, and that that is the expected behavior.

Comment: @JasonB Yeah, I changed it to `f[q - 5, Sequence @@ par]^2 + g[q + 5, Sequence @@ par]` so I could see whether a solution was working. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem you're having is that because Manipulate localizes its variables, while the symbols in `par` are global (in the `` "Global`" `` context), the letters `a`, `b`, `c` inside the `Manipulate` do not refer to the variables in `par`. Your workaround seems reasonable. There's also the option [`LocalizeVariables`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LocalizeVariables.html), which can be set to `False` to make the `Manipulate` parameters global. But on the face of it, I prefer your workaround.  Having global variables under the control of `Manipulate` has caused me headaches in the past.

Another potential solution is to localize `par` inside `Manipulate` and use [`Sequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sequence.html) to feed the arguments to `f` and `g`:

```
Manipulate[
 With[{par = {a, b, c}}, 
  Plot[f[q - 5, Sequence @@ par] + g[q + 5, Sequence @@ par], {q, 0, 10}]
  ],
 {{a, 0}, -1, 1}, {{b, 0}, -1, 1}, {{c, 0}, -1, 1}]
```

You could also inject the symbols into `Manipulate` before the code is passed to `Manipulate` for localization:

```
With[{par = par},
 Manipulate[
  Plot[f[q - 5, Sequence @@ par] + g[q + 5, Sequence @@ par], {q, 0,
     10}],
  {{a, 0}, -1, 1}, {{b, 0}, -1, 1}, {{c, 0}, -1, 1}]
 ]
```

One could also define your functions as a function of a list like this

```
f[q_, {a_, b_, c_}] := q + a + b + c;
```

and call the function like this

```
f[q - 5, par]
```

Comment: I was not aware of the command `With`: I can solve my issue with the combination of `With` and `Sequence` as in your first code example. I anyway find the definition of function of a list even more clear but I cannot really make it working. Do I have to declare `par` in a particular way?

Comment: @GabrieleDeLuca  You'll still have to use `With` (but not `Sequence`).  -- Thanks for the accept.  It might be better to wait a while (like a day).  Sometimes a better answer comes along, especially if when the question is not marked answered on the front page.

Answer (score 1):

There is really no need to gather the parameters into a list. You can do it with this simple approach.

```
DynamicModule[{f, g},
  f[q_, a_, b_, c_] := q + 2 a + 3 b + 4 c;
  g[q_, u_, v_, w_] := q - u/2 - v/3 - w/4;
  Manipulate[
    Plot[f[q - 5, a, b, c]^2 + g[q + 5, a, b, c]^2, {q, 0, 10}],
    {{a, 0}, -1, 1},
    {{b, 0}, -1, 1},
    {{c, 0}, -1, 1}]]
```

It does not matter at all what the formal arguments in a function definitions is named. I changed the name of some them in the definition of `g` to demonstrate that.

What matters in the `Manipulate` is that the actual arguments used in the plotted expression correspond by name and position in the two function calls.

Comment: This is another nice approach but then one still has to write down the arguments needed by the function, although with another name, while calling the list with `With` resembles more what I was looking for.